# Sobre el uso de punteros inteligentes

Tags: c++, punteros, c++11

Supongamos que se tiene el hipotético caso donde se utilizan punteros para todo tipo de variable. Más exactamente, tenemos el siguiente procedimiento para leer los elementos de un arreglo unidimensional:

```
void leer_arreglo(int *&v)
{
    int *i = new int;
    for (*i = 0; *i < dim_v; (*i)++)
    {
        cout << "Elemento " << *i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> v[*i];
    }
    delete i;       
}
```

Como se puede apreciar, incluso la variable `i`, que solo se utiliza para recorrer los elementos del arreglo, es declarada como un puntero a `int`, y como tal, al final del procedimiento se debe liberar la memoria manualmente.

¿Cuál sería la solución más razonable para que la variable `i` permanezca dentro del ámbito del bucle `for` y al mismo tiempo se evite liberar manualmente la memoria asignada para dicho puntero?

Mi primer intento fue el que se tiene a continuación:

```
void leer_vector(int *&v)
{
    for (int *i = new int(0); *i < dim_v; (*i)++)
    {
        cout << "Elemento " << *i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> v[*i];
    }
    delete i;       
}
```

El problema es que se genera un error al momento de llegar a la instrucción `delete i;` pues dicha variable ya no existe fuera del ámbito del `for`.

Después se me ocurrió lo siguiente:

```
void leer_vector(int *&v)
{
    for (int *i = new int(0); *i < dim_v; (*i)++)
    {
        cout << "Elemento " << *i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> v[*i];
        delete i;
    }       
}
```

No obstante, tengo serias dudas de que lo anterior sea una buena idea porque en cada iteración estoy liberando la memoria asignada.

No sabía muy bien que hacer hasta que descubrí a los llamados **punteros inteligentes** (*smart pointers*, gracias Paula_plus_plus) y entonces llegué al siguiente código:

```
void leer_vector(int *&v)
{
    for (auto i = make_unique<int>(); *i < dim_v; (*i)++)
    {
        cout << "Elemento " << *i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> v[*i];
    }       
}
```

Qué bonito, ¿verdad?, la variable `i` está en dentro del ámbito del `for` y no tenemos que preocuparnos de liberar manualmente la memoria asignada. Entonces, surge mi pregunta: **¿es este un uso válido de los punteros inteligentes?**

Hago esta pregunta porque a pesar de revisar algunos enlaces de SO donde se analizan en que casos se deben usar este tipo de punteros, todavía no tengo del todo claro si en mi caso en particular el último fragmento de código que puse sea una solución correcta y aceptable.

Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios y/o respuestas.

Comment: Está *raspando* el cierre por `Basada en opiniones`. No lo voto porque puede ser interesante para otros, pero deberías reformularla.

Comment: @Trauma si, ahora que lo vuelvo a leer, entiendo que mi pregunta pueda ser cerrada por ese motivo. Trataré de reformularla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **¿Es este un uso válido de los punteros inteligentes?**

Claro: el código compila, se ejecuta y no produce errores en tiempo de ejecución ni fugas de memoria; así pues es un uso válido.

Otra cosa es que el código que has mostrado como ejemplo sea un uso *inteligente* de los punteros inteligentes, que a mi entender: no lo es; por ejemplo:

> ¿Cuál sería la solución más razonable para que la variable `i` permanezca dentro del ámbito del bucle `for` y al mismo tiempo se evite liberar la memoria asignada para dicho puntero?

La razón de ser de los punteros inteligentes es precisamente liberar la memoria asignada a ellos, así que si querías que la memoria asignada no se liberase: un puntero inteligente no debería ser tu elección.

---

Los punteros inteligentes fueron introducidos en el estándar C++11, aunque en C++ ya existía un intento de estandarizar el modismo RAII<sup>1</sup> sobre punteros<sup>2</sup> antes del estándar de 2011 ese intento era muy limitado y poco flexible así que se decidió deprecarlo y desarrollar tres tipos de punteros inteligentes:

#### Puntero único ([`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

Envuelve a un puntero que conceptualmente tendrá un único propietario, cuando se deja de usar el puntero o se reasigna, se liberan los recursos que estuviera manejando; es posible mover el puntero entre diferentes ámbitos:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> dame_dato() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> result;
    // Obtenemos dato, de una fuente externa, el dato necesita ser borrado
    // cuando se deje de usar.
    int *puntero_crudo = factoria_de_datos();
    // Asignamos el puntero
    result.reset(puntero_crudo);
    // Devolvemos el puntero inteligente
    return result;
}
```

El `std::unique_ptr` creado dentro de `dame_dato` no libera el puntero asignado al salir de ámbito si no que hace que cambie de propietario, siendo el anterior propietario la función `dame_dato` y el nuevo propietario el llamador de la misma.

#### Puntero compartido ([`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

Envuelve a un puntero que conceptualmente tendrá múltiples propietarios, la cantidad de propietarios del puntero es recordada como un contador atómico manejado por el propio puntero inteligente; creciendo al ganar un propietario y decreciendo al perderlo. Cuando el contador de propietarios llega a cero, se liberaran los recursos que el puntero estuviera manejando, también es posible mover el puntero entre diferentes ámbitos y si en lugar de moverlo se copia se actualizará el contador de propietarios, esto puede ser costoso a nivel de proceso porque manejar dicho contador implica varias comprobaciones de seguridad. El siguiente código:

```
struct S {};

void propietarios(const std::shared_ptr<S> &sp)
{
    std::cout << "Propietarios de " << sp.get() << ": " << sp.use_count() << '\n';
}

void f(std::shared_ptr<S> sp) { propietarios(sp); }

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<S>();
    propietarios(sp); // Referencia: no aumenta propietarios
    f(sp);            // Copia: aumenta propietarios
    propietarios(sp); // Referencia: no aumenta propietarios
    return 0;
}
```

Produciría la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Propietarios de 0x22ea170: 1
> Propietarios de 0x22ea170: 2
> Propietarios de 0x22ea170: 1
> ```

#### Puntero débil ([`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)).

Envuelve a un puntero del que conceptualmente no será propietario, cualquier uso del puntero requiere *bloquearlo* lo que devolverá un puntero compartido, permite saber si existe el objeto al que apunta mediante la función [`std::weak_ptr::expired`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired).

#### ¿Cuándo usar los punteros inteligentes?

Se usará el puntero único cuando sepamos que el recurso apuntado tendrá un único propietario, el puntero compartido será usado cuando el recurso apuntado tenga varios propietarios y el puntero débil se usará para reclamar el uso de punteros compartidos sin apropiarse de ellos (más que temporalmente).

---

1. Gracias por mencionarlo Trauma.
2. El [`std::auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr), deprecado en C++11 y eliminado del estándar en C++17.

Comment: Cuando me refería a que se evite liberar la memoria asignada, hablaba de evitar usar el operador `delete`. Se me pasó usar la palabra "manualmente". Acabo de editar la pregunta.

Comment: Pues yo no lo entendí ;P

Comment: Más allá de eso, su respuesta está genial. Gracias por la explicación sobre los distintos tipos de punteros inteligentes.