# Solo VS code me marca error con un arreglo bidimensional de tamaño variable

Tags: c++, vscode, array-bidimensional

Me indica lo siguiente:

"message": "la expresión debe tener un valor constante -- el valor de variable "f" (se declara en la línea 13) no puede usarse como una constante",

Ese error no me lo marca Dev c++ y lo corre sin problemas, mientras que VS code me muestra ese error y cuando acaba de correrlo a veces sale que mi programa se detuvo.

Aqui esta el codigo. Es un programa que suma dos numeros adyacentes en una matriz y en  los vectores de la tercera columna almacena el resultado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 

int main ()
{
//AQUI SE LE INDICA LA CANTIDAD DE FILAS
int f=1;
cout << "Ingrese cantidad de filas " << endl;
cin >> f;

int z[f][3];
srand(time(0));

cout << " >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"<< endl;
for (int n=0 ;n<f;n++)
{
//LLENADO
  z[n][0]=rand()%1000;
  z[n][1]=rand()%1000;
  //PROCESO
  z[n][2]=z[n][0]+z[n][1];
  //SALIDA
  cout << z[n][0] << " + " << z[n][1] << " =  " << z[n][2] <<endl ;
}

}
```

He intentado declarar const int f y eso crea otros errores que no se porque saltan ni como resolver. Habia encontrado por alli algo relacionado con Visual Studio necesitando saber el tamaño del arreglo y por ende haciendo el manejo de Variable Lenght Arrays  diferente.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es de Visual Studio Code, es que en C y C++ el tamaño de un arreglo debe saberse en tiempo de compilación.

Para lograr tu cometido tienes varios opciones:

- Usar [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) una estructura dinámica (del estándar de C++):

Debes incluir la cabecera `<vector>` primero.

Su funcionamiento es similar al de los arreglos.

Declaras la variable pasándole el tipo del que serán los elementos.

```
std::vector<int> arreglo;
```

Y agregas elementos con [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

```
arreglo.push(4);
```

También puedes crear arreglos multidimensionales poniendo un vector dentro de otro.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arregloBidimensional;
```

- Usar memoria del heap, que debes asignar y liberar manualmente, lo que implica trabajar con punteros:

Para asignar memoria en C++ puedes usar el operador [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

```
int* numero = new int; // Espacio para un valor
int* numeros = new int[10]; // Espacio para 10 números (puedes usar variables para indicar la cantidad)
```

Al terminar de usar dicha memoria, debes liberarla. Para ello tienes el operador [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

```
delete numero;
delete[] numeros; // Nota que cuando asignas espacio para varios valores/elementos, debes usar delete[]
```

Si quieres, también tienes las funciones de C, definidas en `stdlib.h` para realizar dichas operaciones.

- [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).
  Asigna memoria para un arreglo del tamaño indicado y la inicializa en 0 (la llena de 0s).
- [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).
  Asigna una cantidad de bytes de memoria sin inicializar.
- [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).
  Libera la memoria asignada a un puntero.

Un ejemplo:

```
int alto = 3, ancho = 5;
int* tabla = new int[alto * ancho];

// Llenar la tabla
for (int i = 0; i < ancho * alto; i++){
     tabla[i] = i;
}

// Forma de "mapear" memoria en función de 2 números
int x = 3, y = 1;
int elemento = tabla[y * ancho + x];
std::cout << "El elemento en X: " << x << ", Y: " << y << " es: " << elemento << "\n";
std::cout << "Escribe el nuevo elemento para la posición X: " << x << ", Y: " << y << "\n";
std::cin >> elemento;
tabla[y * ancho + x] = elemento;

// Imprimir como tabla
std::cout << "La tabla es:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < alto; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ancho; j++) {
        int ind = i * ancho + j;
        std::cout << tabla[ind] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
delete[] tabla;
```

También quiero mencionar que esta manera es más eficiente que usando vectores, aunque menos segura. Este último punto se puede mejorar con el uso de punteros inteligentes.

Enlaces útiles:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164508/169744

Answer (score 0):

El problema:

El error supongo que lo da porque quieres asignar una cantidad de memoria variable en memoria estática, por como tienes declarada la matriz es altamente recomendable asignarle una cantidad fija de filas y columnas para que a la hora de compilar el programa este vea la cantidad de memoria estática a asignar, pero al ser una variable, dicha cantidad puede cambiar con lo que le metas al programa de forma que en el compilado no se sabe cuanta memoria se necesita.

El hecho de que te salten otros errores a la hora de poner f como una constante creo que es porque quieres cambiar su valor con el cin.

La solución:

Puedes hacer la matriz con memoria dinámica de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
int **z;
z = new int * [f];//Reserva de memoria de las filas
for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
    z[i] = new int[3]; //Reservamos la memoria correspondiente a cada fila
```

y por el resto no haría falta cambiar nada más, no obstante es recomendable borrar la memoria reservada al final del uso de dicha memoria, en tu caso no es necesario ya que es un programa pequeño, pero se haría de la siguiente forma:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
    delete [] z[i];
    
delete [] z;
```

Así debería de solucionarte el problema.