# Como puedo agregarle contenido a este arreglo de tipo char , problema de programacion de subconjuntos

Tags: c++, conjuntos

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void printSubset(char sets[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j))) {
                cout << sets[j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int a=0;
     cout<<"ingrese el numero de elementos:\n" ;
    cin>>a;
  cout<<"ingrese los elementos:\n";
  cin>>b
    char conjunto[a] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    
    int n = sizeof conjunto / sizeof conjunto[0];
    printSubset(conjunto, n);
}
```

tengo el siguiente codigo en c++ que consiste en mostrar los subconjuntos que tiene el arreglo , quiero que el usuario pueda ingresar las letras o bueno los elementos alfabéticos y el programa muestre los subconjuntos.
Intente de esta forma

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void printSubset(char sets[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j))) {
                cout << sets[j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
}



int main() {
    char b;
    int a=0,m;
     cout<<"ingrese el numero de elementos:\n" ;
    cin>>a;
  cout<<"ingrese los elementos:\n";
  cin>>b;
  char conjunto[a] = {};
  m++;
  while(m<<a){
    
  
  conjunto [a]={b};
  }
    
    
    int n = sizeof conjunto / sizeof conjunto[0];
    printSubset(conjunto, n);
}
```

al momento de ejecutarse solo me deja cargarle la primera letra despues el programa queda en blanco y no me deja ingresar mas letras a pesar de haber indicado antes que tenia 3 espacios

Comment: el ejercicio se llama asi ajaja problema de programacion subconjuntos , en el cuerpo del post hice mi pregunta , quiero que el usuario pueda agregar los elementos alfabeticos al conjunto de por si el codigo para que muestre los subconjuntos ya estan

Comment: vale ya entiendo

Comment: no estás declarando `conjunto`, este debe ser un char*...

Comment: No entiendo , hay esta declarado como chat dentro de el while

Comment: debes inicializarlo, además, en el `while(m<<a)` hay una llave demás

Comment: ya lo inicialice de esta forma y ya acomode el while conjunto [a]={b}; por cierto sigue teniendo el mismo error en al linea de int n = sizeof conjunto / sizeof conjunto[0];

Comment: Problema típico: no puedes declarar un arreglo de tamaño variable ni inicializarlo directamente con una variable. Si luego de tener en cuenta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/512628/169744) tienes un problema diferente, edita la pregunta. De lo contrario es un duplicado.

Comment: Como te decía, estás inicializando el char dentro del while, por la cual el `int n` no leerá al char porque está dentro del while, no es variable global...

Comment: aaa tienes razoon

Comment: ya quedo correctamente declarado pienso yo , ahora el problema es que no me deja ingresar mas de 1 letra al programa luego se queda en blanco y no deja hacer mas

Comment: Mejor usa [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)